# How to execute this DirectFB sample?

Tags: c++, g++, directfb

I got the following directFB example code form the [tutorials](http://directfb.org/docs/DirectFB_Tutorials/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <directfb/directfb.h>

static IDirectFB *dfb = NULL;
static IDirectFBSurface *primary = NULL;
static int screen_width = 0;
static int screen_height = 0;
#define DFBCHECK(x...)                                         \
  {                                                            \
    DFBResult err = x;                                         \
                                                               \
    if (err != DFB_OK)                                         \
      {                                                        \
        fprintf( stderr, "%s <%d>:\n\t", __FILE__, __LINE__ ); \
        DirectFBErrorFatal( #x, err );                         \
      }                                                        \
  }
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    DFBSurfaceDescription dsc;
    DFBCHECK(DirectFBInit (&argc, &argv));
    DFBCHECK(DirectFBCreate (&dfb));
    DFBCHECK(dfb->SetCooperativeLevel (dfb, DFSCL_FULLSCREEN));
    dsc.flags = DSDESC_CAPS;
    dsc.caps = DSCAPS_PRIMARY | DSCAPS_FLIPPING;
    DFBCHECK(dfb->CreateSurface( dfb, &dsc, &primary ));
    DFBCHECK(primary->GetSize (primary, &screen_width, &screen_height));
    DFBCHECK(primary->FillRectangle (primary, 0, 0, screen_width, screen_height));
    DFBCHECK(primary->SetColor (primary, 0x80, 0x80, 0xff, 0xff));
    DFBCHECK(primary->DrawLine (primary, 0, screen_height / 2, screen_width - 1, screen_height / 2));
    DFBCHECK(primary->Flip (primary, NULL, 0));
    sleep(5);
    primary->Release(primary);
    dfb->Release(dfb);
    return 23;
}
```

And I'm trying to compile and got the error (from a gnome-terminal):

```
$ g++ Test01HorizontalLine.cpp -I /usr/local/include/directfb/
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘DFBSurfaceCapabilities’
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp:33: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘DFBSurfaceFlipFlags’
```

I'm using DFB 1.4.11 (I can't update for my current project). How can I make this sample run? (newbie)

**--update**

After update the lines (as stated by @jclin):

```
dsc.caps = DFBSurfaceCapabilities(DSCAPS_PRIMARY | DSCAPS_FLIPPING);  
...  
primary->Flip(primary, NULL, DFBSurfaceFlipFlags(0));
```

the result is:

```
$ g++ Test01HorizontalLine.cpp -I /usr/local/include/directfb/
/tmp/cc6iUS1W.o: In function `main':
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `DirectFBInit'
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `DirectFBErrorFatal'
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `DirectFBCreate'
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `DirectFBErrorFatal'
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `DirectFBErrorFatal'
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to `DirectFBErrorFatal'
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp:(.text+0x1ef): undefined reference to `DirectFBErrorFatal'
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp:(.text+0x26d): undefined reference to `DirectFBErrorFatal'
/tmp/cc6iUS1W.o:Test01HorizontalLine.cpp:(.text+0x2e4): more undefined references to `DirectFBErrorFatal' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this because I have no such version right now.

```
dsc.caps = DFBSurfaceCapabilities(DSCAPS_PRIMARY | DSCAPS_FLIPPING);  
...  
primary->Flip(primary, NULL, DFBSurfaceFlipFlags(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Now looks like the problem changed... see my update.

Comment: Did you specify the linking path and library for GCC? -ldirectfb -L/path_to_directfb_lib/

Comment: Thanks! (awarding the bounty to @KBart, for the full compile line)

Answer (score 4):

Below code works on my test ubuntu12, I may have different directfb with yous but should be similar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <directfb/directfb.h>

static IDirectFB *dfb = NULL;
static IDirectFBSurface *primary = NULL;
static int screen_width = 0;
static int screen_height = 0;
#define DFBCHECK(x...)                                         \
  {                                                            \
    DFBResult err = x;                                         \
                                                               \
    if (err != DFB_OK)                                         \
      {                                                        \
        fprintf( stderr, "%s <%d>:\n\t", __FILE__, __LINE__ ); \
        DirectFBErrorFatal( #x, err );                         \
      }                                                        \
  }
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    DFBSurfaceDescription dsc;
    DFBCHECK(DirectFBInit (&argc, &argv));
    DFBCHECK(DirectFBCreate (&dfb));
    DFBCHECK(dfb->SetCooperativeLevel (dfb, DFSCL_FULLSCREEN));
    dsc.flags = DSDESC_CAPS;
    dsc.caps = DFBSurfaceCapabilities(DSCAPS_PRIMARY | DSCAPS_FLIPPING);
    DFBCHECK(dfb->CreateSurface( dfb, &dsc, &primary ));
    DFBCHECK(primary->GetSize (primary, &screen_width, &screen_height));
    DFBCHECK(primary->FillRectangle (primary, 0, 0, screen_width, screen_height));
    DFBCHECK(primary->SetColor (primary, 0x80, 0x80, 0xff, 0xff));
    DFBCHECK(primary->DrawLine (primary, 0, screen_height / 2, screen_width - 1, screen_height / 2));
    primary->Flip(primary, NULL, DFBSurfaceFlipFlags(0));
    sleep(5);
    primary->Release(primary);
    dfb->Release(dfb);
    return 23;
}
```

Build with below command line:

```
 g++ -o testHorizonLine  Test01HorizontalLine.cpp -I/usr/include \
 -I/usr/include/directfb -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -ldirectfb
```

To find where libdirectfb.so is located, you could use linux `find` command, then add `-L` option to g++ command to include library path and add `-ldirectfb` to link libdirectfb.so file.

```
$ find /usr/lib -name libdirectfb.so
```

Run testhorizonLine output:

```
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~| DirectFB 1.2.10 |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        (c) 2001-2008  The world wide DirectFB Open Source Community
        (c) 2000-2004  Convergence (integrated media) GmbH
      ----------------------------------------------------------------

(*) DirectFB/Core: Single Application Core. (2012-05-21 06:43)
(!) Direct/Util: opening '/dev/fb0' failed
    --> Permission denied
(!) DirectFB/FBDev: Error opening framebuffer device!
(!) DirectFB/FBDev: Use 'fbdev' option or set FRAMEBUFFER environment variable.
(!) DirectFB/Core: Could not initialize 'system_core' core!
    --> Initialization error!
Test01HorizontalLine.cpp <24>:
        (#) DirectFBError [DirectFBCreate (&dfb)]: Initialization error!
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you use libraries in your project, including headers is only half of the work. You must also show where the actual library (**libdirectfb.so** in your case) is located so it can be linked to your code. Do this by passing **-L** and **-l** options (also **note** that neither prefix lib- nor externsion .so are required):

```
g++ your_source_file.cpp -I /path/to/include -L/path/to/lib -ldirectfb
```

There are great deal of topics on how to use libraries in your projects i.e. you might want to start [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142103/how-do-i-load-a-shared-object-in-c)

P.S. It is always a good idea to use **-Wall** option to see more information on what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the full compile line (too much things to include...)