# Link .so file to .cpp file via g++ compiling

Tags: c++, linux

i am trying to get a library to work in my c++ project and there is no clear instructions of how to do this for people who are not used to c++

the following [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/33532/) is the closest i have come

it states the following

```
-L/path/to/my/library/folder -ldllname
```

also the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142103/how-do-i-load-a-shared-object-in-c) states the following

```
gcc yourfile.cpp -lblah
```

now from what i can see the command is `-l` + `filename`, for example my filename is `directory/libtest.so` it would be `-ldirectory/libtest.so`, is this correct, could someone clarify

i am currently using the following command to compile my `maincpp.cpp` file, would like to however include a .so file called for example `./directory/libtest.so`

```
g++ -fPIC -o libgetmacip.so -shared -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/linux maincpp.cpp cpptoinclude.cpp
```

Comment: You have to keep in mind that giving a dynamic library to a binary means just to state that this binary shall at execution time be linked to *a library of that name* (not *that* library).  At execution time, such a library must be present in the *system* (e. g. in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH), so it does not make much sense to give a specific directory for it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> now from what i can see the command is `-l + filename`, for example my filename is `directory/libtest.so` it would be `-ldirectory/libtest.so`

No, that's not correct.  It should be `-Ldirectory -ltest` i.e. you use `-L` to add a directory to the search paths where the linker will look for libraries, and you say which libraries to link to with `-l`, but to link to `libtest.so` or `libtest.a` you say `-ltest` without the `lib` prefix or the file extension.

You *can* link by naming the file explicitly, without `-L` or `-l` options, i.e. just `directory/libtest.so`, but for dynamic libraries that is almost always the wrong thing to do, as it embeds that exact path into the executable, so the same library must be in the same place when the program runs. You typically want to link to it by name (not path) so that the library with that name can be used from any location at run-time.

Comment: Well it's pretty clearly documented if you bother to read the GCC docs https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Comment: Also be aware that you won't _include_ the .so in your own .so, you will just link to it, making your .so depend on the other one, not include its contents.

Comment: Hey @JonathanWakely, I think I did exactly what you said. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967646/link-a-shared-library-with-g yet still ran into an error. Can you shed some lights please?

Answer (score 5):

This is a step by step procedure of how to create and link a .so with .cpp file

1. Create .cpp file that you want to convert to .so.
   Example -
   `#include<stdio.h>
   int add(int a , int b)
   { return a+b;}`

   > Save it by name add.cpp
2. Create .so with following command
   `gcc -c -fPIC add.cpp -o add.o`

   > This creates libadd.so
3. Create a .cpp file which will use this .so file
   Example-
   `#include<stdio.h>
   extern int add(int a, int b);
   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
    printf("Hello the output is %d \n",add(10,15));
    return 0;
   }`

   > Save it as main_file.cpp
4. Create a .o file from this file using this command
   `g++ -c main_file.cpp`
5. Link .so with .o using this command
   `g++ -o prog main_file.o -L. -ladd`

   > Here L specifies the folder with the .so file
   >   And -l specifies the name of the .so library
6. Run the program with the command
   `./prog`

Comment: Thanks this example was very useful for me.  
I think it is missing a step:
2.a gcc -shared -o libadd.soo add.o

Comment: needs to be "gcc -shared -o libadd.so add.o" (just .so instead of .soo) ... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**pkg-config**

I like to use `pkg-config --cflags --libs libtest` to generate the compiler flags and linker flags for me. The source code installation just needs to provide a `.pc` file, and put it in a directory that's listed in PKG_CONFIG_PATH, e.g., `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`. You can use it like this:

`g++ -o myprogram myprogam.c` pkg-config --cflags --libs libtest`

**Rebuilding the linker cache**

Even if `LD_CONFIG_PATH` contains `/usr/local/lib`, and your shared object library ( the `.so` file ) is located there, you still might get an error like

`error while loading shared libraries: <INSERT LIBRARY NAME>.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

If your linker cache `/etc/ld.so.cache` has not been rebuilt since the library was installed.

You can fix this by running `ldconfig` ( or `sudo ldconfig`, depending on the `/etc` directory permissions, which are likely only writeable by the root user ).

When successful, `ldconfig` prints no output. For more detailed output when running `ldconfig`, use the `-v` ( or `--verbose` ) flag.

If you have ever run into this error, and then it magically fixed itself while you were troubleshooting, it's probably because you followed someone's advice and did something like

`ldconfig -v | grep <INSERT LIBRARY NAME>`

to make sure the `.so` file was in a directory listed in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, like `/usr/local/lib`. It's a reasonable troubleshooting step to perform if you already confirmed that directory is included in `/etc/ld.so.conf` or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`, but `ldconfig -v` still *runs* `ldconfig` in verbose mode, which rebuilds `/etc/ld.so.cache`, and probably fixed your issue.

If your error mysteriously fixed itself after some time without you having to run `ldconfig`, then something else on your system must have run it since then - e.g. a startup script, a scheduled task, or installation scripts for other software.