# CMake: Not to use /usr/lib64/libXmu.so

Tags: cmake, geant4

I am new to CMake and Geant4. I am trying to build a project using them.
Also, I am working in a remote cluster. When I `cmake`, there's no error. But when I do `make` the error I am getting is,

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib64/libXmu.so', needed by 'PRO_simulation'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PRO_simulation.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

however,

```
ls -rt /usr/lib64/libXmu*
```

gives:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     15 Jan 11  2016 /usr/lib64/libXmu.so.6 -> libXmu.so.6.2.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 109552 Nov 20  2015 /usr/lib64/libXmu.so.6.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     16 Jan 11  2016 /usr/lib64/libXmuu.so.1 -> libXmuu.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  19440 Nov 20  2015 /usr/lib64/libXmuu.so.1.0.0
```

Since its a remote cluster I cannot do a link with the name "libXmu.so" (After requesting the cluster authorities, still there's no use), but I can do the link to my local directory.

Now my question is what should I do in cmake such that, it will look for `libXmu.so` in my local directory instead of `/usr/lib64/libXmu.so`

Comment: would it be helpful if you do `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/local:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` cmake ..`

Comment: No, that doesn't help. Sorry, I edited the question now. When I do `cmake`, there are no issues. The error occurs when I do `make` after that. There's a file named `build.make` which has a line `/usr/lib64/linXmu.so`. That is why `make` is looking at that specific path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is a hack and by no means a proper solution, but you can link directly to a `.so` file: [Link .so file to .cpp file via g++ compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208932/link-so-file-to-cpp-file-via-g-compiling)

1. Open CMakeLists.txt and remove all references to libXmu linking in `target_link_libraries` for all targets.
2. Add `/home/user/path/to/libXmu.so` to the cmake CXX or link flags. More information on how to do that can be found in: [How do I add a linker or compile flag in a CMake file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-do-i-add-a-linker-or-compile-flag-in-a-cmake-file) or: [Set CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS options using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085945/set-cflags-and-cxxflags-options-using-cmake)

I would recommend that you first try something such as:

```
export CFLAGS=/home/user/path/to/libXmu.so
export CXXFLAGS=/home/user/path/to/libXmu.so
```

Before running cmake. If this fails, open CMakeLists.txt and try to find where extra `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` are defined and add the path to libXmu.so

Another thing that you can do is you can run `make VERBOSE=1`, which will show you the exact gcc/g++ command issued, copy it in a text editor and replace `-lxmu` with `/home/user/path/to/libXmu.so`

I hope at least one of those works.