# How to correctly include and link a proprietary shared object library in C++

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, g++, .so

I have a linux c++ sdk that i need to integrate as a dependency into a .NET 6.0 bigger project.

This sdk is **only** conditionally included for the linux version of the software, i do already have the windows version running with no problems.

This skd exposes only classes in very nested namespaces, and as far as i'm aware, `[DllImport]` does not support class methods.

I do already know how to create a wrapper and [expose functions with `extern "C"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/using-cpp-interop-implicit-pinvoke?view=msvc-170) and passing the sdk instances as pointers to a .NET Core application running with no problem under linux systems

My problem is that i do have no idea on how to succesfully compile/include/link the existing `.so` files into a .dll or .so that i can then `[DllImport]`

The sdk has been sent to me with the following structure (take name-of-lib as the placeholder name. I'm not sure if i can expose the real company name so i won't just in case):

```
run/
|- x86/
|  +- {same files as x64 but i don't target x86 arcs so it's useless}
+- x64/
   |- install.sh {see #1}
   |- libNameModuleA.so.1.2.3
   |- libNameModuleB.so.3.2.1
   |- libNameApi.so.7.8.9
   +- {etc. etc.}
lib/
|- lib-name-api/
|  |- doc/
|  |  +- somehtmlautogenerateddocs.html
|  |- include/
|  |  +- NameApi.h
|  +- source/    {optionally for the top level apis}
|     +- {varius header .h files}
|- name-of-lib-module-A/
|  +- {same as previus, repeat for every .so file}
+- {etc. etc.}
```

{#1} script that craetes links as libName.so => libName.so.1 => libName.so.1.2 => etc

All of those library header files reference each other like they were in the same folder, using an `#include "subLibraryModule.h"` even if this file would actually be in something like `../../subLibrary/include/subLibraryModule.h`.

Also, in the skd there are only headers.

now, what would be the (either, i don't really know waht would be the best tool) cmake, make, g++, gcc command, configuration or procedure to be able to include the top-level header that references all of the other ones in the compilation without a `file not found` error from the compiler?

Say i need to compile a single file `wrapper.cpp` that includes only the top level headers and contains only `extern "C"` functions

I've tried doing this with vscode and intellisense actually resolves the headers correctly, but when i try to compile it everything bursts into a fire of file-not-founds

Am I missing something? Is there further information or files i missed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, because `[DllImport]` works (in .net 6.0 on linux too) only for functions compiled with extern in the global scope. My problem is that this library exposes only classes, and i need to compile a wrapper around it. I should specify that too, yeah...

Comment: I highly doubt you can turn a .so. Into a dll or call one from the other, But I would like to be proven wrong here.

Comment: I mean, i don't really need to compile a .dll; net core under linux can import native .so https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/cross-platform. i just need a way to compile a wrapper library that i can then do interop stuff with the CRL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i figured it out.

### makefile

The only problem here is that i did not know how to use a glob pattern to include stuff automatically (like `-Ilib/*/include`) but whatever.

```
CC := g++
SRC := wrapper.cpp
OBJ := wrapper.o
OUT := libWrapper.so
INCs := -Ilib/lib-name-api/include -Ilib/name-lib-module-A/include {etc. etc.}
LIB := -L/usr/local/lib/installedLibNameSos/ -lNameModuleA -lNameModuleB {etc. etc.}

all: $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -shared -o $(OUT) $(LIB)

$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    $(CC) -c $(SRC) -o $(OBJ) $(INCs) $(LIB)
```

### wrapper.cpp

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "NameApi.h"
// varius using namespace and other import stuff


extern "C" int test (){
    return 42;
}

extern "C" string somethingReturningAString (){
    // calls and stuff to the native library
    return "Hi mom"
}
```

obviusly the .so needs to be copied where the executable is

### csharpClass.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// extension not needed.
// the library will be loaded along with the required .so's
// that have been linked from /usr/local/lib/installedLibNameSos/
[DllImport("libWrapper")]
extern static int test ();

[DllImport("libWrapper")]
extern static string somethingReturningAString ();


Console.WriteLine(test());
// 42
Console.WriteLine(somethingReturningAString());
// Hi mom
```

resources:

- [Link .so file to .cpp file via g++ compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208932/link-so-file-to-cpp-file-via-g-compiling)
- [Call C++ library in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574801/call-c-library-in-c-sharp)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services (p/Invoke examples)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/cross-platform

(note: the process works perfectly. But i've been using a library written and documented by a spastic monkey. So yeah i've literally learned the basics of g++, make and got crippling depression for nothing. lol)